# Is it possible to skip the previous day when using the "dateadd" and "getdate"?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL and I am trying to get data from my system from the past seven days, but need to be a day behind due to synchronization of multiple databases.

If today is April 5th, I need information from the previous seven days starting with data from April 3rd and back.

Below is the query I am using. I am using SQL Server and this query (summarized) is built into a scheduled job.

```
SELECT 
    INCUNITS.INCNUM AS [Event ID]
FROM 
    INCUNITS   
WHERE 
    DISPDATE > Dateadd(dd, -7, getdate()) 
    AND INCUNITS.OSTIME > '0'
```

I've tried -1 or -2 after getdate or interval -1 but I am not able to skip the previous day

Comment: what is the data type for `DISPDATE` ?

Answer (score 2):

So, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    INCUNITS.INCNUM AS [Event ID]
FROM 
    INCUNITS   
WHERE 
    DISPDATE between Dateadd(dd, -7, getdate()) and Dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())
    AND INCUNITS.OSTIME > '0'
```

So, go back 7 days, and only go up to 2 days ago. You may want to fiddle with the numbers for your use case. For example if you wanted 7 days ago starting from 3 days ago, you probably want something like

```
 DISPDATE between Dateadd(dd, -9, getdate()) and Dateadd(dd, -3, getdate())
```